# magento - retrieve values from catalog/eav_attribute

Tags: php, magento

Ive added a field to catalog/eav_attribute and managed to save data into it. I just cant figure out how to get the data out in the front end.

im using the event observer "catalog_product_load_after" and im trying to extract "is_featured_attribute" from the "catalog/eav_attribute" resouce, im fairly new to magento and just cant figure out how to get the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Dave

Comment: What is your attribute type? Text, dropdown, multiple select..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could show what your observer function looks like, but I'll hypothesize. Essentially you need to load the product from the observer to retrieve your attribute value;

```
public function yourClass($observer) {

// Get the observed product
$item = $observer->getProduct();

// Get value of your attribute (guessing Yes or No)
$myAttr = $item->getIsFeaturedAttribute();

if($myAttr == 'Yes') {

   // Do something
   $isItYes = true;

} else {

   // Do something
   $isItYes = false;

}

return $isItYes;
}
```

Comment: Guess what happens when you observe catalog_product_load_after and you load product in your observer :)

Comment: Reindex Em All - good shout!  didnt noticed he was using load_after, infinite loop oclock.  I've tweaked my answer.